# Zend framework 2 PHP requirement

Tags: php, zend-framework, zend-framework2

Can we run Zend framework 2 on PHP 5.5, PHP 5.6 or any latest version?

This official requirement link says: [PHP 5.2.11 or later](http://framework.zend.com/manual/1.12/en/requirements.introduction.html).

This official FAQ link says: [Zend Framework 2 is based on PHP 5.3. We expect to add support for PHP 5.4 once it starts to be adopted by the PHP community.](http://framework.zend.com/about/faq/)

Comment: For what it's worth, I'm running ZF2 on PHP 5.6 on a personal app of mine with no issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, of course you can run the current release version of ZF on the current release version of PHP. The requirements page you linked to is for ZF 1.x. When the FAQ says 'add support for PHP 5.4' it means adding support for features which are only available in 5.4 or above (such as traits), not that the code won't work on 5.4 out of the box.

Comment: I just updated the link which says same thing for Zend framework 2. But your answer makes sense.